# Android - How should i load image files in to a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, bitmap, gallery

Let's say I have a Camera X activity that captures and stores pictures.

Then I have a Gallery activity with a RecyclerView that gets filled with those images.
Here is what I currently have:

a Photo class which saves bitmaps generated with captured files:

```
    class Photo(
    private val bitmap: Bitmap,
    private val landBitmap : Bitmap, ) {

    private var view : GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder? = null

    fun setView(view : GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder?){
        this.view = view
    }

    fun getView() : GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder?{
        return view
    }

    fun getBitmap(flag : Boolean) : Bitmap{
        if(!flag) return bitmap
        else return landBitmap
    }
}
```

These bitmaps are being generated in the main activity as a background process.

```
        val directory = File("${getExternalFilesDir(null)}/images/").listFiles()
    if (directory != null) {
        lifecycleScope.launch{ // Generate Bitmaps
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                for(file in directory){
                    Gallery.setBitmap(file)
                    runOnUiThread{
                        if(Gallery.isRecyclerViewInitialized())
                            Gallery.getRecyclerView().adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Gallery.setBitmap()

```
        fun setBitmap(file : File) : Bitmap?{
        val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(file)
        val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fileInputStream, null, options)
        if (bitmap != null) {
            val resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels, 1500, true)
            val landBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 730, 800, true)
            photos.put(file.name, Photo(resizedBitmap, landBitmap))
            return bitmap
        }
        return null
    }
```

The problem is that the process takes too long. How do I deal with picture files? I tried working directly with ImageView.setImageURI() but his performance is terrible.

I considered using Threads instead of Coroutines.That would speed up the process.

Example: The default android gallery application loads pictures instantly.

Comment: Have you tried using a library like Glide? It will resize the images for the target view and cache the resized images for faster reloads. Alternately, if you launch a coroutine per file instead of processing them sequentially in a single coroutine you may get some speed up from parallel processing. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72930584/firestore-recycleview-image-holder/72930828#72930828) for some examples.

Comment: @TylerV Glide looks like it could be the solution. I'm gonna try that.

Comment: @TylerV Finally I got what I wanted, I used Picasso instead of Glide and also a Thumbnail system to speed up the gallery loading even more. Thank you so much.